# Show that $XY=0$ or $YX=0$

Tags: matrices, determinant, cayley-hamilton

We have $X,Y$ $(2×2)$ matrices with complex entries and $X=A^{2}-B^{2}$ and $Y=AB-BA$. We know that $\det(X)=\det(Y)=0$. Show that $XY=0$ or $YX=0$.
I see that Trace of $Y$ is $0$ and $\det(Y)$ is also $0$ so by $C-H$, $Y^{2}=0$. I also saw how we can write $(X+Y)$ as $(A-B)(A+B)$ but nothing more.

Comment: What are $A$? $B$? Where did you get this? Context for this problem is needed, please!

Comment: A and B are 2×2 matrices that is all we know. The problem is from Mathematical Gazette from Romania

Comment: How did you see that $Y^2=0$ ?

Comment: Trace of Y is 0 and det(Y) is also 0 so by C-H we get $Y^{2}=0$

Comment: @StefanSolomon you should put the context into the OP....

Comment: Why is det$(X)=0$. If say $A = 2I$ and $B=I$, then det$(X)$ is certainly not $0$! Are there further conditions on $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Mike I think OP is saying that $\det(X) = \det(Y) = 0$ is given.

Comment: Very few people are in a hurry such extreme when asking a question that are forced to write things like C-H. Among those, none write it as a math formula.

Answer (score 3):

If $X=0$ or $Y=0$, there is nothing to prove. Assume that $X,Y\ne0$. Recall the following identity for $2\times2$ matrices:
$$
\det(X+Y)+\det(X-Y)=2(\det(X)+\det(Y)).
$$
By assumption, $\det(X)=\det(Y)=0$. Therefore
$$
\det(X+Y)+\det(X-Y)=0.\tag{1}
$$
Let $D=A-B$ and $S=A+B$. Then $DS=X+Y$ and $SD=X-Y$. Hence $(1)$ implies that $\det(SD)+\det(DS)=0$, i.e., $2\det(D)\det(S)=0$. Therefore one of $S$ or $D$ must be singular.

It follows that $Av=\pm Bv$ for some nonzero vector $v$. Thus
$$
Xv=(A^2-B^2)v=AAv-BBv=A(\pm Bv)-B(\pm A)v=\mp Yv.\tag{2}
$$
Since $X$ and $Y$ are singular, nonzero and $2\times2$, they must be rank-one matrices. Let $X=x_1x_2^\ast$ and $Y=y_1y_2^\ast$ for some nonzero vectors $x_1,x_2,y_1$ and $y_2$. Note that $y_1\perp y_2$ because
$$
y_2^\ast y_1=\operatorname{tr}(Y)=\operatorname{tr}(AB-BA)=0.
$$
Now return to $(2)$. There are two possibilities:

1. $Xv=\mp Yv=0$. Then $x_1(x_2^\ast v)=\mp y_1(y_2^\ast v)=0$. Therefore both $x_2$ and $y_2$ are orthogonal to $v$. Hence $x_2$ is parallel to $y_2$. In turn, $x_2$ is orthogonal to $y_1$ and $XY=x_1(x_2^\ast y_1)y_2^\ast=0$.
2. $Xv=\mp Yv\ne0$. Then $x_1(x_2^\ast v)=\mp y_1(y_2^\ast v)\ne0$. Therefore $x_1$ is parallel to $y_1$. In turn, $x_1$ is orthogonal to $y_2$ and $YX=y_1(y_2^\ast x_1)x_2=0$.

Comment: Where did you get this identity for 2x2 matrices? It is probably easy to verify by direct calculation, but my question is if there is some natural way to see it.

Comment: @PhoemueX Simply expand the exterior product $(x_1+y_1)\wedge(x_2+y_2)+(x_1-y_1)\wedge(x_2-y_2)$ directly to get $2(x_1\wedge x_2+y_1\wedge y_2)$. The analogous formula is actually true for all bilinear forms, not just for the alternating ones.